# Graph implemenatation in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap

Which is a better way to implement a graph in Java? **Array** of **Lists** or **HashMap** in which **keys** are vertices and **values** are List. What would be complexity and what are the trade offs between space and memory in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

In a graph, in most case, you've not a lot of path relative to the number of points so use a 2d-array would have lot of null  : useless

You have several option, one can be a `HashMap<Point,List<Point>>` where key is a Point (attributes can be coordinate, value, ...) and key is the List of points that are connected with the key

Small ex : 
[image]

```
Map : key /  value (I represented as array, but it's List of course)
       1  /  [2,5]
       2  /  [1,3,5]
       3  /  [2,4]
       4  /  [3,5,6]
       5  /  [1,2,4]
       6  /  [4]
```